# multiple upload with multiplecrop for yii2

Tags: php, yii, crop, fileapi, yii2

Is it possible to use multiple crop (with multiple upload) in FileApi or FileApi Advanced ? 
via this Yii2 libraries

https://github.com/vova07/yii2-start/blob/master/common/extensions/fileapi/FileAPI.php

or

https://github.com/vova07/yii2-start/blob/master/common/extensions/fileapi/FileAPIAdvanced.php

At least: my task it's make photo gallery. With multiupload, crop, to every photo in submodel can be attached description, title and checkbox for is it cover for album

Relation : Gallery HAS_MANY Gallery_photos

any suggestions, other libraries ?

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/51243-imagefile-upload-in-yii2/
May be this help

Answer (score 0):

You can do this but, you need to add this functionality by your self.
At this moment I write an extension FileAPI for Yii 2, that will can do multiple upload and crop at the same time by default.
For future details watch [this](https://github.com/vova07/yii2-start/issues/40) issue.